# How do i generate a unique id using UUID() which starts with an alphabet

Tags: java, string

I have to generate a unique ID for a user name which contains the following reg-ex

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{3,19}
```

I have to use the UUID() to generate the string and I have made the username 6 characters in length. I am trying to replace the first character with alphabet, its not working. The code I have written is :

```
String unique = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String name = unique.substring(30);
String username = name.replaceFirst("[a-z]{0}", name));
```

Comment: Define `its not working`?  What's it doing?  How do the actual results compare to the expected results?

Comment: Its appending the value of the name to username and username becomes 12 chars in length. The first character in the result string is not changing to an alphabet.

Comment: [a-z]{0} means you are encountering a-z character 0 times... how could you use that to replace anything?

Comment: Even if I delete {0} , the result is the same.

Comment: Do you mean "with a letter"?  An alphabet would be the set of all letters.

Comment: Sorry, the first character should be a letter.

Comment: **Why?** The result will no longer be a UUID.

Comment: Well the username field is set to have first character as a letter. hence i need to generate unique id everytime i run the test, I should replace the first letter with a letter.

Comment: Either the username starts with a letter or it is a UUID. You just have to decide. If you want the properties of a UUID, specifically pretty good uniqueness,my don't get to dictate what the first character must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing in

```
String username = name.replaceFirst("[a-z]{0}", name));
```

is replacing once part of `name` that matches regex `[a-z]{0}` with `name`, so effectively you are replacing first empty string with value from `name`. Since firs empty string can be found at start of all strings you are placing `name` in front of `name` like for example for `name` `"921fab"` result will be `"921fab921fab"`.

---

If you want to replace first character of string with character in range `a-z` then maybe first generate this character with

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

and then add it to substring of `name` which will contain all its characters starting from character at position 1.

```
String username =  c + name.substring(1);
```